# Celery not queuing to a remote broker, adding tasks to a localhost instead

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

My question is same like this [Celery not queuing tasks to broker on remote server, adds tasks to localhost instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860356/celery-not-queuing-tasks-to-broker-on-remote-server-adds-tasks-to-localhost-ins), but the answer is not working to me.

My celery.py

```
# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

app = Celery('project', broker='amqp://<user>:<user_pass>@remoteserver:5672/<vhost>', backend='amqp')
# app = Celery('project')
# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

When I run:

$ celery -A  worker -l info

I receive the following output:

```
 -------------- celery@paulo-Inspiron-3420 v4.2.1 (windowlicker)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.15.0-36-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic       2018-10-30 13:44:07
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         mycelery:0x7ff88ca043c8
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://<user>:**@<remote_ip>:5672/<vhost>
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
            .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

I tried stop rabbitmq server and uninstalled it too, but celery keeps queuing to localhost.

Someone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add something like this to your `__init__.py` file in the same directory as the celery.py file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Also, make sure you're starting the worker process from inside your project's virtualenv.